# PyCharm unable to generate code skeletons, autocomplit, run debug mode with docker interpreter

Tags: docker, pycharm, apple-m1

I am using PyCharm with docker interpreter on macbook with M1. At some point of time it stopped generating code skeletons, providing autocompletion and run debug mode of my code.
When I've tried to run PyCharm in Debug mode it stated me 502 docker error.
Reseting to factory defaults and re-installations didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of issue was Docker Desktop's Beta feature `Use containerd for pulling and storing images`. It failed the whole process. Uncheck it and live happily.